# How to read only double values in a file

Tags: java

I have a file like this

```
07/15/14: 19.33

07/15/14: 13.14

07/15/14: 21.20

07/15/14: 22.67
```

I need a method to read those double values and print out the average.  This is how the numbers are saved.

```
public void hourlyOverall() throws IOException
{
    //construct the date to print into a file
    java.sql.Date date=new java.sql.Date(time);
    //set hourlyOverall variable
    hourlyOverall=tips/hours+hourlyWage;
    //construct the printwriter with a file writer in it.  
    //set the FileWriter append parameter too true so that the 
    //info is added onto the end of the file, and the file is
    //not overwritten
    PrintWriter editFile=new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("wage info",true));
    editFile.printf("%tD: %.2f \n ", date, hourlyOverall);
    editFile.close();
}
```

This is how I'm trying to read them.

```
public double totalHourlyOverall() throws FileNotFoundException
{
    Scanner fileScanner=new Scanner(fos);
    while(fileScanner.hasNextDouble())
    {
            total+=fileScanner.nextDouble();
            counter+=1;
    }
    fileScanner.close();
    return overallHourly=total/counter;
}
```

It's not picking up the doubles though.  What am I doing wrong?

edit:

So I'm getting an array out of bounds exception now.  My code is like this

```
public double totalHourlyOverall() throws FileNotFoundException

{
    Scanner fileScanner=new Scanner(fos);
    while(fileScanner.hasNextLine())
    {
            String str=fileScanner.nextLine();
            String[] array=str.split(":");
            total+=Double.parseDouble(array[1]);
            counter+=1;
    }
    fileScanner.close();
    return overallHourly=total/counter;
}
```

There should be an array[1] since each line is split into two, right?

Comment: Why, oh why, are you using `java.sql.Date`?

Comment: Array index out of bounds = you need to skip blank lines. You can do so by checking if the length of the resulting array < 2.

Comment: Because java.sql.Date does what I want to be done.  Why should I not use it here?

Answer (score 2):

There's an easier way to do it:  read each line in, and split on a common token in the line.

I won't write out *all* of the code, but here's an approach for reading the entire line:

```
while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
    String[] lineFragments = line.split(":");
    // the date is in lineFragments[0]; the number is in lineFragments[1].
    // I leave the rest as an exercise to the reader.
}
```

Comment: I think you want to split on `": "`

Comment: `Double.parseDouble()` will be fine with whitespace in it.  [Its backing implemenation will use `trim()`](http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/misc/FloatingDecimal.java.html) to remove the whitespace character(s).

Comment: what about new Double (String) or BigDecimal?  I do not see the use of `Double.parseDouble()` in the OP's code.

Comment: @ScaryWombat:  That's kind of the point that I'm nudging the OP towards.

Answer (score 2):

hasNextDouble is going to return false for "07/15/14" and you will stop reading right there.

Answer (score 0):

Another way you could do it is with a `Pattern` and `Matcher`

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(\\b[-\\d\\.]+\\b)");   // pattern to match any double value (+/-) with boundaries
Matcher m;
while(fileScanner.hasNextLine()) {
    String line = fileScanner.nextLine();
    m = p.matcher(line); // try to match the regular expression
    if ( m.find() ) {
        String value = m.group(1); // get the match in group 1
        // turn to a double, etc...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should just read line by line, then skip 10 characters, and read up to the end of line.